# PHP zip getStream() always return false in a online server. Locally works great

Tags: php

I have a form where I upload a zip file. Then on submission form, I extract that zip using PHP and ZipArchive class.

It works great locally using WAMP. But if I upload it online, my $fp variable is always FALSE instead a RESOURCES.

Any suggest?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][0]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
  $internalFile = $zip->statIndex($i)['name'];
  $fp = $zip->getStream($internalFile);

  var_dump($internalFile); // <--- I get for example "text1.txt"

  var_dump($fp);  // <----locally using WAMP I get a 'resource". Online I get always FALSE

  var_dump($zip->getStatusString()); // <--- I get always "No Error" message. also if $fp is FALSE!!! WHY??

  ....

}
```

Comment: Does your server have the [ZIP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.requirements.php) installed/enabled? Check with `phpinfo()`

Comment: @brombeer yes. if I output var_dump($internalFile) I see name of file inside zip.

Comment: Can you use the getStatusString function in order to get more details about why the getStream returns false?

Comment: @OfirBaruch yes I already used it. It get "No Error" message always.... also if $fp is FALSE instead RESOURCES.... i don't undestand why!